# Why doesn't this makefile take effect

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I wanna use Google Closure Compiler to compile my js codes.I write a makefile to do the job but it never takes effect.
What I want is to compile each file listed in filelist and output it to ../js/

```
filelist = thermometer.js logic.combat.js analyse.js logic.js

wp := $(foreach k, $(filelist), ../js/$(k))

$(wp) : $(filelist)
    java -jar compiler.jar --js=$< --js_output_file=../js/$<
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current formulation, all of the wp objects depend on all js files, and only the first source file is ever compiled (thermometer.js).

You should rather formulate the last two lines in the Makefile with pattern rules:

```
all : $(wp)
../js/%.js : %.js
    java -jar compiler.jar --js=$< --js_output_file=$@
```

Comment: Nah, the output is not `../js/$@`, the path is in `$@` already.

Comment: Thanks. But I get an error here. It seems that Line 2 doesn't unfold correctly.     make: *** No rule to make target `../js/logic.combat.js', needed by `all'.  Stop
.

Comment: Stupid question, but necessary nontheless: Did you get the tab right and does logic.combat.js exist? If both are true, look at the output of make -rd.

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably need some target to trigger it, like:

```
all: $(wp)
```

Second, you're going to get a command `java -jar compiler.jar --js=../js/thermometer.js --js_output_file=../js/../js/thermometer.js` for every single file. Which is not likely to be your goal. I think you want something like that:

```
../js/%.js: %.js
    java -jar compiler.jar --js=$< --js_output_file=$@

all: $(addprefix ../js/,$(filelist))
```